# What is the maximum attainable height of a red-black tree with black-height k and why?

Tags: algorithm

What is attainable height in red-black tree? Is it the height of the tree? I have read the wiki of it but still have no clue. Thank you.

Comment: A clue from the wikipedia article: "If a node is red, then both its children are black." What does this imply about the number of red nodes in a connected path from root to leaf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since a node of height h has black-height >= h/2, the answer should be 2k.

Black Height of a Red-Black Tree :
Black height is number of black nodes on a path from a node to a leaf. Leaf nodes are also counted black nodes. From above properties 3 and 4, we can derive, a node of height h has black-height >= h/2.